# DataTypes and ResTypes in x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to start with x86 Assembly, but there is one thing i don't understand. A Byte variable, a word variable, a double word variable, and so on, what means?
It means that the space for that variable is of 1 byte,2 byte,4 byte, and so on? I don't think so, but for this reason i ask for your help. I don't think so because in the string variable there is "db", but there are 11 characters, so 11 bytes. I'm confused.

[image: Answer the question referring to these declarations for example.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It does not mean "maximum space" for that variable, it does mean *exact* space for that variable:

- 1 byte for BYTE(db),
- 2 byte for WORD(dw),
- 4 byte for DWORD(dd),
- 8 byte for QWORD(dq)

That's all. Nothing special.

Comment: I edited the post. Yeah, maybe i've not expressed myself correctly, i wanted to say the same thing you said. But why there is "db" for the string variable (in the image) if every character is 1 byte, and so the string is composed of more than a single byte?

Comment: It's just for your comfort. Instead of a sequence of BYTEs like `strng db "H","e","l","l","o"," ","w","o","r","l","d"` it is shortened to `strng db "Hello world"`. You could also, in a similar way, create a sequence of WORDs: `seqOfWords dw 1234, 4567, 8900`

Comment: So when there is an array or a string, db,dw,dq, and so on are refered to the single element, not the entire collection of elements, right?

Comment: The label denotes the point(er): that can be a single element or a sequence of elements. If just points to the first element, because in assembly there are no real sequences or arrays or the like. Just pointers to some address, useful or not.

Comment: Ok, now i understand. Was the string the one thing i hadn't understood. Thank you very much!

Comment: Every character is not always 1 byte only. Windows uses UTF16 where characters are encoded in two (or sometimes four) bytes and Linux uses UTF8 with variable size of 1..4 characters. For the list of data types used in assembly see https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/#DataTypes